# How can I print all the positions in my array on a TextMesh on Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D text linked to a public TextMesh. I want all the elements on my public string array to be displayed on that 3D text. When I try to run it on a for loop it runs through all the strings in my array and prints the last position. What I need it to do is to display in that TextMesh all of the strings in my array. I tried to do it with a foreach loop as well, but same result.

This is what I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myShoppingList.Length; i++){
        listText.text = (myShoppingList[i] + "\n");
    }
```

When I hit play, I can only see the last position in my array in the 3DText (although I know it has run through all of them). This is the foreach loop I tried and got the same result with:

```
foreach (string item in myShoppingList) {
        listText.text = (item + "\n");
    }
```

Basically what I need is a way for it to say

```
listText.text = (myShoppingList[0] + "\n" + myShoppingList[1] + "\n" + myShoppingList[2] + etc.)
```

I could do it like that, but then if I want to add an item to my list (my string array) I would have to get into this code and add another position at then end. So maybe there is a smart way to do this that I am not seeing!

Any thoughts? Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Replace `=` with `+=` because `=` is changing the last string value

Comment: Thank you!!!! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`=` will assign the variable to a new value. It's replacing the old text with the current element's.

Instead, you want to append it. That's the `+` operator.

You can append the new text to the existing contents of `listText.text` and assign the result of that to `listText.text` itself (`listText.text = listText.text + moreString`), or, more conveniently, use the `+=` operator, with is the shorthand for appending followed by assigning to self (`listText.text += moreString`).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of using a loop, you could use the `string.Join()` method, which will take an IEnumerable or an array, and join all the items with any string (like a newline character, in your case).

For example:

```
listText.Text = string.Join("\n", myShoppingList);
```